# SQL query to get rows with 2 or more duplicates in one column and no duplicates across two other columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
So say my table is:
#3 6 4#
#4 5 6#
#4 6 4#
#8 6 4#
#1 2 3#
#1 3 2#
#4 5 6#
```

I would like to get the rows where there are 2 or more duplicates in the first column and no duplicates across the other 2.

```
So my result should be:
#1 2 3#
#1 3 2#
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is you code?  What have you tried?

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You at least completed the 2-minute site tour. So many people don't, so good job on that at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `count()` [`over()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

rextester: http://rextester.com/TVW19929

```
create table temp (a int, b int, c int);
insert into temp values (3,6,4) ,(4,5,6) ,(4,6,4) ,(8,6,4) ,(1,2,3) ,(1,3,2) ,(4,5,6);

with cte as (
  select t.a, t.b, t.c
      , aCount = count(*) over (partition by t.a)
      , bCount = count(*) over (partition by t.b)
      , cCount = count(*) over (partition by t.c)
    from temp t
    )
select a, b, c
  from cte
  where aCount > 1
    and bCount = 1
    and cCount = 1;
```